# Custom summary for class template (c++)

Tags: c++, lldb

In LLDB it's possible to have custom formatting. For example having

```
class Foo { ... };
```

I can do

```
type summary add -T Foo
```

and then provide python script with custom summary. Then having

```
Foo f;
```

I can use custom formatting in LLDB:

```
frame variable f
```

But how to do in a generic way ? Having

```
template<typename T> class Foo { ... };
```

I can define summary for concrete types like

```
type summary add -P Foo<int> ...
type summary add -P Foo<double> ....
```

but is it possible to do it for all types ? 
I would like to have something like

```
type summary add -P Foo<T> ...
```

Or maybe there is a different way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the DWARF debug information records only information about individual concrete instantiations, lldb (and debuggers in general) don't have a great comprehension of abstract templates.

The way to handle templates for type summary matching at present is to use the -x option to `type summary add`.  That tells lldb to treat the type name as a regular expression.  It's not that hard to craft regular expressions to match template type names.  There are examples of using this in the type summaries for llvm data types here:

http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/utils/lldbDataFormatters.py?view=markup

This is discussed in the section `REGULAR EXPRESSION TYPENAMES` in http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html